# Pyodbc: How to pass tuple as query param?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

Quick rundown:

The idea here is to read some data in from a csv file, and use that as the list in the `NOT IN` part of my sql query. I'm connecting to the db (.mdb) with the code below. 
Note `LP` is the tuple/list I'm trying to pass, `IRdb` is the path to the db

```
constr = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=' + IRdb
conn = pyodbc.connect(constr, autocommit=True)
cur = conn.cursor()

IRsql='''SELECT IRRPResults.RRPName, IRRPResults.PointName, IRRPResults.RiskPerTime FROM IRRPResults 
WHERE IRRPResults.PointName<>? 
AND IRRPResults.RRPName NOT LIKE ? AND IRRPResults.PointName NOT IN ?'''

cur.execute(IRsql,('Total',r'Conn%',LP))
```

The issue:

Everything works fine except for the execute statement (which did work before i added the `NOT IN` part). I've tried passing `LP` as string, tuple, and list, but nothing seems to be working. I get the following error

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] In operator without () in query expression 'IRRPResults.PointName<>Pa_RaM000 AND IRRPResults.RRPName NOT LIKE Pa_RaM001 AND IRRPResults.PointName NOT IN Pa_RaM002'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone interested, or for that guy reading this 2 years from now with the same issue, or my future self when I forget what i did, I've figured out a solution or two.

The first work around was to simply use `.format` on the sql string to insert `LP` directly before it gets passed to the execute statement.

```
IRsql='''SELECT IRRPResults.RRPName, IRRPResults.PointName, IRRPResults.RiskPerTime FROM IRRPResults 
WHERE IRRPResults.PointName<>? 
AND IRRPResults.RRPName NOT LIKE ? AND IRRPResults.PointName NOT IN {}'''.format(LP)

cur.execute(IRsql,('Total',r'Conn%'))
```

The other solution, I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561405/getting-sql-error-when-trying-to-pass-a-python-list-into-a-sql-query), is a little more elegant and clever in that it builds a string of '?' markers for each element in LP. Then LP gets passed as a tuple/list to the execute statement.

```
placeholders=','.join('?'*len(LP))
IRsql='''SELECT IRRPResults.RRPName, IRRPResults.PointName, IRRPResults.RiskPerTime FROM IRRPResults 
WHERE IRRPResults.PointName<>? 
AND IRRPResults.RRPName NOT LIKE ? AND IRRPResults.PointName NOT IN ({})'''.format(placeholders)

cur.execute(IRsql,('Total',r'Conn%',*LP))
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. I was tinkering with this exact problem for more than an hour. I would like to add that if you want to make your query to be dynamic to include only one value, then keep in mind that a dfault tuple with len 1 looks like this: `(1,)` where '1' is what you want as a parameter for your in or not in SQL statement. That format with a comma at the end would not work with SQL, so an alternative would be to transform `(1,)` to `(1,1)` with something like:`a = [1]`
   `if len(a) == 1:`
        `a.append(a[0])`
    `b=tuple(a)`
    `b`