# Getting SQL error when trying to pass a Python list into a SQL query

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to pass a Python list into a SQL Server query (in Python). I have formatted the query correctly so that there are question marks in the query as placeholders. The code is as follows:

(vsList is the name of the list of strings)

```
placeholders = ','.join('?'*len(vsList))


query = ("select distinct cf.cfname \
          from jiraschema.customfield cf inner join jiraschema.customfieldvalue cfv on cf.id = cfv.CUSTOMFIELD \
          where (cfv.DATEVALUE is not null \
                 or cfv.NUMBERVALUE is not null \
                 or cfv.STRINGVALUE is not null \
                 or cfv.TEXTVALUE is not null) \
                 and cf.id not in (select cf.ID \
                                   from jiraschema.customfield cf inner join jiraschema.fieldscreenlayoutitem fsli on 'customfield_' + cast(cf.id as nvarchar) = fsli.FIELDIDENTIFIER \
                                                                  inner join jiraschema.fieldscreentab fst on fsli.FIELDSCREENTAB = fst.ID \
                                                                  inner join jiraschema.fieldscreen fs on fst.FIELDSCREEN = fs.ID \
                                   where fs.id in (%s))" % placeholders)

fields = cur.execute(query, *vsList)
```

When I execute this code, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deidle\Python\fieldsNotDisplayed.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\deidle\Python\fieldsNotDisplayed.py", line 100, in main
    ndFields = getFieldsNotDisplayed(viewScreens)
  File "C:\Users\deidle\Python\fieldsNotDisplayed.py", line 76, in 
getFieldsNotDisplayed
    fields = cur.execute(query, *vsList)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server 
Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] 
 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be 
prepared. (8180)")
```

I have checked a lot of other documentation about passing a list into a SQL query  and have tried many of the solutions, but can't get anything to work with my code. Like I said, I know the format of the query is correct with the question marks as parameter markers, so I know it must be something with my list.

Comment: After you generate query, print it and see if it is syntactically correct (it isnt, but it should help to see it). I'm guessing your list at the end if not formatted right.

Comment: Read through your string and mentally increment by 1 for a `(` and decrement by 1 for `)`. You should end on zero; your string ends on 1

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for your comment. I fixed that problem, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: @dfundako This was my problem. I originally had 'query' in the cur.execute statement rather than as a separate string and the backslashes were ok then, but did not work for a correct format of the string. Thank you!

Comment: maybe dumb question but why is the query in `()`?

Comment: @SuperStew I don't think it's necessary, but I like to put the parentheses to contain everything since there was formatting done at the end